# Dropdown Menu working error when used with multiple dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with dropdown menu from W3Schools where it is working in case of single dropdown option. Its [link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click)

But is not working when I am making it with two drop down menu, even when I changed the GetElementById to GetElementsByClassName. Here is the fiddle link for [not working code](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/d0bwdqtp/).

**code.html**

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"  onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown1</a>
<div class="dropdown-content myDropdown">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown2</a>
<div class="dropdown-content myDropdown">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 </div>
</li>
```

```
 function myFunction() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}


 window.onclick = function(e) {
 if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle wasn't working because `myFunction` wasn't defined (if you open developer console in your browser, you will notice an error). That is because jsFiddle wraps your javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
  // HERE comes your code
}//]]> 
</script>
```

So your function will be available only within the scope of window.onload function but not outside, to make your function available to your html,  you have to define it in global scope which is `window`.

Then you can actually start playing with your function and you will see that `document.getElementsByClassName("myDropdown")` is returning all your dropdown elements as array. The simplest solution would be to add `this` parameter to calling of `myFunction` in html. And in your function just toggle "show" class to next element.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Dropdown1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content myDropdown">
      <a href="#">Link 11</a>
      <a href="#">Link 21</a>
      <a href="#">Link 31</a>
    </div>
</li>

function myFunction(el) {
  el.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
}
```

Here you will notice there is another problem when clicking on Dropdown1 and then on Dropdown2 the first dropdown won't disappear. Here is working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/d0bwdqtp/3/) demo :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code by giving both dropdowns id.

```
        <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"  onclick="myFunction(this)">Dropdown1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content myDropdown" id="dropdown1">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction(this)">Dropdown2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content myDropdown" id="dropdown2">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
    </li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Click on the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>




    <script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction(a) {
        //alert(a.nextElementSibling.id);    
        var divId = a.nextElementSibling.id;
        document.getElementById(divId).classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(e) {
      if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```